# How to Access Files on my computer through Docker

Tags: windows, docker, file-not-found

I am running Docker on my Windows 10 Home computer. I am trying to run the following code

```
 $ docker run -i -t -v /Users/Maddy/Desktop/Docker:/home bcain/lensing /bin/bash
```

which gives me the following

```
 DOCKER-lensing >
```

which then I can input the program I need to run (lenstool) that uses a file on my computer (MACS0417.par) which lives on my computer in /Users/Maddy/Desktop/Docker

```
Docker-lensing > lenstool MACS0417.par -n
```

which then gives me

```
You are running openMP version of lenstool with 1 threads
You can change the number of threads by set environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS
ERROR: file MACS0417.par not found
```

The path to the files I want to access from my computer was specified with

```
-v /Users/Maddy/Desktop/Docker
```

I have researched other similar questions that aloud me to check to see if my **local drive** was successfully located under **docker volume** and It is.
to check this I did the following:

```
docker volume ls
```

which reads

```
DRIVER                 VOLUME NAME
local                   UsersMaddyDesktopDocker
```

Am I missing something? I am a beginning coder and begining Docker user. Thank you for your time and I probably left some vital information out so please ask what other information you need. Thank you in advance,
-Maddy

UPDATE May 22nd 2018-

I have looked up and followed the directions for docker compose. I am now trying to edit the volumes but am not quite sure how I would go about doing this. The code I have in my yml file so far is this

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

I understand that I need to add something under volumes but I am not sure what I should put? (I am currently looking more into this but if anyone can guide me more I would be very appreciative!)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mount anything then you will have to map it from your local to the desired location on the container.For that you need to create a docker compose file , inside that yaml there is place holder called volumes there you need to specify the location of  local file : to the place in the container. You can search for docker compose documentation and you will get an idea.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help! I have looked up and followed the directions on the docker compose documentation and will add more of my questions about this above